# как перевернуть словарь в python?

Tags: python, словари

у меня есть такой код:

```
num = int(input())


result = {}
while num != 0:
    result[int(num)] = int(num) ** 3
    num -= 1


print(result)
```

он заполняет словарь от 1 до num, где значения это ключи возведенные в 3 степень. Работает он корректно только начинается не с 1 как мне надо а получается с конца, например:
{8: 512, 7: 343, 6: 216, 5: 125, 4: 64, 3: 27, 2: 8, 1: 1}, а мне нужно что-бы словарь начинался не с 8 до 1, а с 1 до 8.

Comment: Словарю пофиг, сортирован он, или нет (хотя в последних версиях Python порядок добавления хранится). Однако в вашем случае ключи - небольшие целые числа, так почему бы не использовать простой список, где индекс играет роль ключа?

Comment: `print({i: i ** 3 for i in range(1, int(input()) + 1)})`

Answer (score 2):

Решение с циклом for:

```py
num = int(input())

result = {}
for i in range(1, num + 1):
    result[i] = i ** 3

print(result)
```

Comment: спасибо, позже отмечу как ответ, пока не могу)

Comment: А зачем i в int преобразуйте? 

Comment: Просто копировал код и как-то не придал значения. Поправлю.

Answer (score 0):

Ты начинаешь с `num` и заполняешь словарь, пока `num` не станет 0. Начинай с 1 и заполняй, пока не дойдёшь до `num`